# Django - change a field's widget in subclass of BaseInlineFormSet

Tags: django, formset

I have a form that is a subclass of BaseInlineFormSet, and for one of the fields in the related model, I like to change its widget. Here is my code for the form:

```
class MyForm(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.forms[0].error_css_class = 'error'
        self.forms[0].required_css_class = 'required'

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

        # here I am trying.
        # recommend is an IntegerField in MyModel, which -
        # I like to make it render in the form as a Radio Select (yes, no)
        widgets = {'recommend': {forms.RadioSelect}}
```

Any help and input is appreciated

Comment: To start `BaseInlineFormSet` doesn't use an inner `Meta` class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An inline formset is a collection of model forms. The `Meta` class doesn't belong on the formset, it belongs on a model form.

Usually, you would create the inline formset class using the `inlineformset_factory` method, which can take `form` as an argument.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {'recommend': forms.RadioSelect()}

MyModelFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ParentModel, MyModel, form=MyModelForm)
```

If you do have to subclass `BaseInlineFormset`, you can provide formset as an argument to `inlineformset_factory` as well.

Have a look at the [inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) documentation for more information.

Comment: I tried your solution. I am having 2 issues: 1- when I exclude fields in the Meta class inside MyModelForm, the parent field (foreign) always appears in the form, in addition to the Id. 2- I have to use extra=1 otherwise the form won't display

Comment: only if I explicitly loop through the visible fields in the template, that the foreign field(key) disappears. still, what about the extra=1?

Comment: You haven't shown your template, but it sounds like you're rendering the formset manually. The foreign key is a hidden field in the form, so you should treat it separately. See e.g. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields. If it works with `extra=1`, then I'm not sure what the problem is?

Comment: yes I am rendering the formset manually the same way as in the link you provided, and it renders correctly. It is good if it works with extra=1 but I am trying to understand why. Isn't extra=1 supposed to be plus 1 additional form? Thanks for your input.

Comment: `extra=1` means it will display a form for every exisiting instance in the database, and one extra (empty) form (unless the `max_num` setting is used, which limits the total number of forms).

Answer (score 4):

To incorporate the widget in a BaseInlineFormSet class.......

Override the "add_fields" method in your subclass:

```
def add_fields(self, form, index):
    super(MyForm, self).add_fields(form, index)
    form.fields["recommend"].widget = forms.RadioSelect()
```